# C# Rounding 2 decimals: Truncate vs Round

Tags: c#, truncate, rounding

I would like to know which are the advantages and disadvantages using Truncate or Round when rounding a float to 2 decimals:

```
float number = 3.4567070
Math.Round(number, 2)
Math.Truncate(100 * number) / 100
```

Which is the best and eficent one? When to use round and when truncate?

Comment: in your example, your using truncate to act as the round function..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Truncate is marginally more efficient, but these are very different functions.

- [`Math.Round`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round) computes the nearest number to the input to a specified degree of accuracy.

  > Rounds a value to the nearest integer or to the specified number of fractional digits.
- [`Math.Truncate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.truncate) effectively discards the any digits after the decimal point. It will always round to the nearest integer toward zero.

  > Calculates the integral part of a number

Which function you should use is entirely dependent on the logic you're trying to implement.

Here's a quick sample output of each function:

```
Input | Round | Truncate
------+-------+---------
 -1.6 |    -2 |       -1 
 -1.5 |    -2 |       -1 
 -1.4 |    -1 |       -1 
 -0.5 |     0 |        0 
  0.5 |     0 |        0 
  1.4 |     1 |        1 
  1.5 |     2 |        1 
  1.6 |     2 |        1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to round to 2 decimals, I ***highly*** recommend using `Round()` instead of `Truncate()`, if for no other reason than readability & maintainability.  Your example is a bit confusing at first glance, and it takes some analysis to understand that it is effectively using some fancy footwork to get the `Truncate()` method to perform a rounding operation.

In general, when writing code, you should use the "correct" method first, and if benchmarking shows a performance issue, *only then should you attempt optimizations* such as your "tricky" code example.

Answer (score -1):

That depends on your purpose.  I don't think one is more effecient than the other.  It's like saying "Should I use a nail or a screw?"  They do different things.